# Not able to display column entries using Data Reader

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, c#-4.0

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("My path");
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataReader dr;

Label1.Text = Session["name"].ToString();

con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select '"+Session["name"]+"' from table1",con);
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(dr.read()){
   Dropdownlist1.Items.Add();   ------->Stuck here
}
```

I am selecting a column from a table which will have 3 or more entries. And I want to put them in dropdownlist. I tried different approaches but nothing is giving me output I require. It shows error or display first entry only.

Please feel free to edit my code and provide a suitable idea.

THANKS

This is my table:

```
SKY  |  SEA  | LAND
-----------------------
EAGLE| SHARK | LION
CROW | FISH  | TIGER
DUCK | WHALE | DEER
```

Where `Session["name"]` can be SKY/SEA/LAND and depending on that I want my drop down to show the entries below it IF SKY is Session["name"] then dropdwonlist should display EAGLE CROW DUCK

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @karthi - I tried different ways and those gave me different errors.What i mean is I used some methods which might give me the output but all failed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on your question you are passing Session["name"] which is your table Column Name to your select query.

There is also need to change on your code:

Lets say your Session["name"] value is **SKY**

```
"Select '"+Session["name"]+"' from tableA" --session["name"] is treated here as a string
```

this will be rendered as `Select 'Session[Name]' from TableA` which is incorrect.
so the result will be :

```
Session[Name]
Session[Name]
Session[Name]
```

Remove the single quote on the query and let's say : Session["name"] value is **SKY**

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select "+Session["name"].ToString()+" from table1",con);
```

the query will be -> `Select SKY from table1`

and the select result

```
EAGLE 
CROW 
DUCK
```

If so try this  :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("My path");
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataReader dr;

Label1.Text = Session["name"].ToString();

con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select "+Session["name"].ToString()+" from table1",con);
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

       while (dr.Read())
        {
                   // get the results of each column
                   Dropdownlist1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString()); //this will get your first column even your Session["name"] will contain any column values

        }
```

Check also this tutorial: [Lesson 04: Reading Data with the SqlDataReader](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson04)

Best Regards

Comment: The Session["name"] is a value and it will select the appropriate column from table.Consider that column has values like US,WE,I ...I want my drop down list to show US,WE and I.But your code shows the Session["name"] thrice on dropdown list

Comment: i updated my code,try it again..i remove the ' single quote on the sqlcommand

Comment: It doesnt give error but it displays Session["name"] thrice inside dropdownlist..See my data table for clarification.For example it shows SKY three times on dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
 while (dr.read()){
      Dropdownlist1.Items.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
 }
```

If you want to go get only once and without also having to specify the column name then you could use GetString(0) like:

```
 while (dr.read()){
      Dropdownlist1.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0));
      break;
 }
```

Comment: @Edper--Gives Index out of range exception

Comment: The "Name" is only an example you could use your own column name there or you could use GetString(0) instead as @marc_s posted. Now, if you want to do it once you could use break.

Answer (score 0):

you should use like below

```
while (dr.read()){
  ListItem l = new ListItem(dr["name"].ToString(), "value", true);
  Dropdownlist.Items.Add(l);
}
```